# Is there an possibility to put an icon in textinput box in shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am working on a project which involves an input box with filter options of more than 10000, In terms of functionality wise.. its able to search the input. But i also want to put an search icon on the input box.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible code example.

Comment: column(5,selectizeInput("id", choices = list, label = 'Enter your Number', 
       selected = NULL,width = '600px'),offset = 3)                                                                                    This is the text box i am creating it has a drop down which comes as default.. but i want search box instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `searchInput` function in `shinyWidgets` package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyWidgets/index.html